# Ignoring XHTML markup when editing with jEditable

Tags: jquery, forms, jeditable

I am using jEditable to edit a table inline, the third column of which contains email addresses. This column contains plaintext, but it is converted to `mailto:` links using jQuery . Currently, when jEditable is activated, the user sees this: `<a href="mailto:example@example.net">example@example.net</a>`

How do I force jEditable to treat these `<td>`s as plaintext, so that the user making the changes won't have to deal with HTML and will instead just see this: `example@example.net`?

This is the jQuery concerned:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var init;
    $('table#data tbody td').editable( 'media/support/save.php', {
        event: "dblclick",
        submit: "OK",
        cancel: "Cancel",
        tooltip: "Double-click to edit...",
        "callback": function(sValue,y) {
            alert('The server has been updated.'); 
            var aPos = init.fnGetPosition(this); 
            init.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
        }
    });

    var init = $("table#data").dataTable({
        "sDom": 'lfr<"clear">tip<"clear">T', 
        "bStateSave": true,
        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
            $('table#data tbody tr').each(function() {  
                var email = $(this).find('td:last');
                $(email).html('<a href="mailto:' + $(email).text() + '">' + $(email).text() + '</a>');
            }); 
        },
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    });
});
```

I apologize for the big chunk of code, but most of it seemed important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to setup a test page but here's an idea. I looked at the jEditable source and it has an event called 'onedit'. This event is triggered before the actual edit is performed. Subscribe to this event and change the content of the cell to normal text. In the callback function, reformat the value to have a mailto:link.

Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var init;

    $('table#data tbody td').editable( 'media/support/save.php', {
            event: "dblclick",
            submit: "OK",

            //I am assuming that 'this' will refer to the 'TD' which user double clicked on.
            //If not, change the code accordingly.
            onedit : function(settings, self) { $(this).html($(this).text()); }

            onreset : function(settings, original) 
                      { 
                         //We have added 'emailAddress class to our TD in initial setup.
                         //When user cancels editing and the cancelled cell has the 'emailAddress' class,
                         //we format it to have mailto link.
                         if($(this).hasClass('emailAddress'))
                         {
                            $(this).html('<a href="mailto:' + $(this).text() + '">' + $(this).text() + '</a>')
                         }
                      },

            cancel: "Cancel",
            tooltip: "Double-click to edit...",
            "callback": function(sValue,y) {
                    alert('The server has been updated.'); 

                    //TODO: If the edited cell was the email cell, if yes, then format the email with mailto link.

                    var aPos = init.fnGetPosition(this); 
                    init.fnUpdate( sValue, aPos[0], aPos[1] );
            }
    });

    var init = $("table#data").dataTable({
        "sDom": 'lfr<"clear">tip<"clear">T', 
            "bStateSave": true,
            "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                $('table#data tbody tr').each(function() {  
                var email = $(this).find('td:last');
                    $(email)
                        .html('<a href="mailto:' + $(email).text() + '">' + $(email).text() + '</a>')
                        .addClass('emailAddress'); //Add 'emailAddress' class so that we can idenfiy this cell during onreset of jEditable.

                    }); 
        },
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    });
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

From looking at the source, jEditable fires 'onreset' event if user clicks cancel. I have updated the code above. Try it.

**EDIT 2:**

Modified the code so that when user cancels editing, email address is formatted correctly. To achieve this, we add 'emailAddress' class to TDs which contains emails. This class is checked in the onreset method.

Comment: This works almost perfectly. The only glitch is that if the user tries to edit the email column, but then cancels out of doing so, the text remains plain. 

Is there a way to call my `mailto:` creation function if the user cancels?

Comment: How would one verify the selected column contains emails? Given that the `onedit:` rule changes the text to plaintext, could one use a regex to check for email structure and then use the same conversion function to change it to an email link? If so, how would one go about this? Something like: `if ( $(this).text === regex) { //email function }` ? I'm not really sure how to go about formatting or adding the necessary regex..

Comment: You could do that OR add class 'emailAddress' to TDs with email address. You can check for this class in your onreset method. I have updated the code to show the complete example.

Answer (score 1):

I just corrected and completed the previous answer: 
*onReset* is a little bit tricky, jEditable overwrites (restores) with the original content the container (here TD element) after our onReset function ends. So we should overwrite this "backup value" instead of replacing the html/form with a new value.

Additionally there is no $(this) object in that onReset context, this is the second trick.

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var init;

    $('table#data tbody td').editable( 'media/support/save.php', {
            event: "dblclick",
            submit: "OK",

            //I am assuming that 'this' will refer to the 'TD' which user double clicked on.
            //If not, change the code accordingly.
            onedit : function(settings, self) { $(this).html($(this).text()); }

            onreset : function(settings, original) 
                      { 
                         //After onEdit function ends, jEditable saves automatically the current value into a "revert" attribute. This means that we get back the text formatted email after clicking on the Cancel button (and not the html formatted)!
                         //Instead of replacing the current FORM element, we should overwrite this backup value, which is stored in the form's parent element. JEditable restores automatically this value after this onReset function ends.

                         //We have added 'emailAddress class to our TD in initial setup.
                         //When user cancels editing and the cancelled cell has the 'emailAddress' class,
                         //we format it to have mailto link.
                         curr_form = this[0];          //FORM object
                         par = curr_form.parentNode;   //TD object
                         if($(par).hasClass('emailAddress'))
                         {
                             par.revert = '<a href="mailto:' + par.revert + '">' + par.revert + '</a>';
                         }
                      },

            cancel: "Cancel",
            tooltip: "Double-click to edit...",
            "callback": function(sValue,y) {
                    alert('The server has been updated.'); 

                    //If the edited cell was the email cell, then format the email with mailto link.
                    if($(this).hasClass('emailAddress'))
                    {
                         $(this).html('<a href="mailto:' + sValue + '">' + sValue + '</a>');
                         init.fnAdjustColumnSizing();
                    }   
            }
    });

    var init = $("table#data").dataTable({
        "sDom": 'lfr<"clear">tip<"clear">T', 
            "bStateSave": true,
            "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                $('table#data tbody tr').each(function() {  
                var email = $(this).find('td:last');
                    $(email)
                        .html('<a href="mailto:' + $(email).text() + '">' + $(email).text() + '</a>')
                        .addClass('emailAddress'); //Add 'emailAddress' class so that we can idenfiy this cell during onreset of jEditable.

                    }); 
        },
        "aaSorting": [[ 0, "asc" ]]
    });
});
```